# Is there a way to insert Keyboard Glyphs in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Here on the StackExchange framework we have a nice feature, which is apparently called "Keyboard Glyphs" (cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs):

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Is there a way (e.g. with an Add-On) to do the same in Google Docs?
I browsed the Add-Ons but did not find anything, maybe it's hidden somewhere different (e.g. in a Code Formatting Plugin).

Answer (score 2):

There are add-ons which support HTML markdown conversion, however not **`<kbd></kbd>`** tag, but you can do pretty much everything via inserting Drawing:

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

...and then there are symbols like:

⌘ ✲ ⎈ ^ ⌃ ❖ ⌘ ⎇ ⌥ ◆ ◇ ✦ ✧ ⇧ ⇪   ⇪ ⇫ ⇬ ⇮ ⇯   ⇭   ↩ ↵ ⏎ ⮰ ⌤ ⎆ ▤ ☰  ⎄ ⭾ ↹ ⇄ ⇤ ⇥ ↤ ↦ ⎋ ⌫ ⟵ ⌦ ⎀ ⎚ ⌧ ↖ ↘ ⇤ ⇥ ⤒ ⤓ ⇱ ⇲ ⇞ ⇟ △ ▽ ▲ ▼ ⎗ ⎘ ↑ ↓ ← → ◀ ▶ ▲ ▼ ◁ ▷ △ ▽ ⇦ ⇨ ⇧ ⇩ ⬅ ➡ ⬆ ⬇ ⎉ ⎊ ⎙ ⍰ ❓ ❔ ℹ  ☾ ⏏ ✉   ⌂ ✂ ✄ ⎌ ↶ ↷ ⟲ ⟳ ↺ ↻ Ⓐ Ⓑ Ⓒ Ⓓ Ⓔ Ⓕ Ⓖ Ⓗ Ⓘ Ⓙ Ⓚ Ⓛ Ⓜ Ⓝ Ⓞ Ⓟ Ⓠ Ⓡ Ⓢ Ⓣ Ⓤ Ⓥ Ⓦ Ⓧ Ⓨ Ⓩ etc.

which depends on the font you use (if not supported by the font you will see squares/glyphs or nothing)

- **http://www.i2symbol.com/symbols**
- **http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_computing_symbols.html**

Comment: So there are HTML converters, but they do not support <kbd>-tags, which are actually HTML features? That's a pity.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 yes indeed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdxiV.png (answer updated)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Add-ons can't add this kind of feature to Google Documents but could help to achieve something similar.

Stack Exchange's keyboard glyph is actually an HTML feature based on the use of the **kbd** tags (`<kbd></kbd>`). Google Documents doesn't support the use of HTML tags but it allows the use of UNICODE characters like ⏎ (return symbol),  emojis like ⌨️ (keyboard), inline images like [image] and Google Drawings.

NOTE: If you are looking for an add-on recommendation please ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: The other answer says that HTML conversion is supported, might both answers be merged to receive the result?

Comment: I think that "HTML markdown" is misleading. AFAIK there's HTML, there's Markdown and Markdown converters to HTML but not "HTML markdown"